# open path folder don't click main window mfc

Tags: mfc

i working with mfc open save path, i want click open save path don't allow click main window, my code open save path :

```
void CFTPDlg::OnBnClickedButtonSave()
{
    BROWSEINFO   bi; 
    ZeroMemory(&bi,   sizeof(bi)); 
    TCHAR   szDisplayName[MAX_PATH]; 
    szDisplayName[0]    =   ' ';  

    bi.hwndOwner        =   NULL; 
    bi.pidlRoot         =   NULL; 
    bi.pszDisplayName   =   szDisplayName; 
    bi.lpszTitle        =   _T("Please select a folder for storing received files :"); 
    bi.ulFlags          =   BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS;
    bi.lParam           =   NULL; 
    bi.iImage           =   0;  


    LPITEMIDLIST   pidl   =   SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);

    TCHAR   szPathName[MAX_PATH]; 
    if   (NULL   !=   pidl)
    {
         BOOL bRet = SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl,szPathName);
         if(FALSE == bRet)
              return;
         //AfxMessageBox(szPathName);
         m_editSave = szPathName;
         ((CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_SAVE))->SetWindowText(szPathName);
    }
}
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Set the owner window correct to your main window. Otherwise the modal dialog can't disable your window.

Comment: sorry i don't understand, how to don't allow click main window when open diaglog save ?

Comment: The browser select window disables YOUR window when you offer it a handle. You set bi.hwndOwner to NULL. Use your main window handle here. May be reading some basics for windows would help too.

Comment: thanks i have solution, that is bi.hwndOwner = m_hWnd;